# How to handle conversion error on null value?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can anyone please suggest how to handle this conversion error which we getting due to below line :
If (@Xml<>0 or @Xml=null or @Xml='')

Below is the error line:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 11361 Royal Enfield 0 1 to data type int.

Comment: `If (@Xml<>'0' or @Xml is null or @Xml='')`

Comment: Also empty string is not equal to zero or null, so no need to check this with different condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot it work ..